# How can you add a "dead" link to the Current Navigation on the left-hand side?

Tags: 2013, current-navigation

The problem I run into is a matter of needing a header on the left-side navigation for an organizing title but I don't want it to actually link anywhere. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is going into Site Settings -> Navigation.

Scroll down to the Structural Navigation: Editing and Sorting section of the page.

Here select "Add Heading..." create the title you desire and just put nothing in the URL section - sometimes SharePoint would automatically insert the Default site page's URL and this is why this problem came about.

After that click OK on the pop-up and then OK to save your Navigation changes.